# How to trim zero's from price in Magento 1.7.0.2 (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, magento

Here is the code:

```
function wpTrimZeroRight(price, precision) {
var format = {
    'pattern': '%s',
    'precision': precision,
    'requiredPrecision': precision,
    'decimalSymbol': '.',
    'groupSymbol': '',
    'groupLength': 0,
    'integerRequired': 2
};
var xPrice = formatCurrency(price, format);
var decimal = '';
var pointPos = xPrice.lastIndexOf('.');
if (pointPos !== -1) decimal = xPrice.substr(pointPos);
var c1 = decimal.length;
decimal = decimal.replace(new RegExp("[0]+$", "g"), "");
var c2 = decimal.length;
var xPrecision = precision - (c1 - c2);
return xPrecision;
```

This piece of code is taken from webandpeople trim price extension. It does the job but in configurable and bundle producs trim all zeros; so when the price looks like £11.50 on the category page on product page looks like £11.5 . The idea is to have two decimal numbers everywhere except where products cost £0.012 for example. I have played with the code a bit and I changed   (new RegExp("[0]+$", "g"), "");     to     (new RegExp("00", "g"), "0") This gives me £28.990 on some products but the correct amount of £55.50 on the others. I think there is lack of if statement but nothing with much sense comes to my mind. I already spent few hours searching for the answer here and on the other magento related sites. I would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Number.toFixed method is what you are lookign for. (12.5001).toFixed(2) --> 12.50

Comment: But if this change the prices like 0.012 to 0.01 ? It won't work out. I think it has to be statement "if" or something like that to remove zeros to keep two decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to trim a price. I think magento automatically does it.

Use code like Mage::helper('core')->currency($price, true, false);
wherever you are getting price. I think you would get the price in formatted manner

Comment: Somehow Magento display prices differently in category and in product page. When I disable this extension, Magento format prices like: £4.0 where I want (my boss) £4.00